# Error while sending mails using EWSJavaAPI

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to send mails from my java web application by using EWS Java api. But ia m getting an error when sending mails. We have Exchange 2013 server installed.

Here is my code

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username","password");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);    
    try {
        service.setUrl(new URI("host/ews/Exchange.asmx"));
        service.setTraceEnabled(true);
        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
        msg.setBody(MessageBody
                .getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("emailAddress");
        msg.send();
    } 
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is the trace report and error log

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2014-08-14 05:58:04Z">
POST /ews/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-type : text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate
Keep-Alive : 300
User-Agent : ExchangeServicesClient/0.0.0.0
Connection : Keep-Alive
Accept : text/xml


</Trace>

<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2014-08-14 05:58:04Z">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1"></t:RequestServerVersion></soap:Header><soap:Body><m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendOnly"><m:Items><t:Message><t:Subject>Hello world!</t:Subject><t:Body BodyType="HTML">Sent using the EWS Managed API.</t:Body><t:ToRecipients><t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>emailAddress</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox></t:ToRecipients></t:Message></m:Items></m:CreateItem></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:719)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:36)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:140)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:461)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:530)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:214)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:125)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.send(EmailMessage.java:253)
at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:28)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest.executeRequest(HttpClientWebRequest.java:300)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.emit(ServiceRequestBase.java:326)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:714)
... 8 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EwsX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(EwsX509TrustManager.java:62)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1201)
... 27 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem solved. Added the certificate for my exchange server in java. This site helped- https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification