# Certificate erore of Outlook using API java. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException"

Tags: java, ssl, exchangewebservices

From what I have found on net, seems to be a certificate SSL.
I have  searched on  internet, modality how resolve this issue, but all informations what I was  found are incomplete or is for Gmail or others
MY QUESTIONS :
- What kind of certificate for OUTLOOK I need
- Where I can found this certificate
- What are the steps to install it
-What settings I need to do

PLEASE, help me! I try to resolve this problems for a long time. Even good tutorials are OK.
Bellow is my code

```
public class SendEmail {

    public  void sendEmail() {
        try {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

                    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "pass");

                    service.setCredentials(credentials);
                    System.out.println("sendemail 4");
                    service.setUrl(new java.net.URI("https://" + "My company domain"
                        + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

                    service.setTraceEnabled(true);
                    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
                    msg.setImportance(Importance.High);
                    msg.setSubject("Hello world!");

                    msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Mesaj trimis din JAVA"));
                    msg.getToRecipients().add("oncioiu_dan_ionut@yahoo.com");
                    msg.send();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

MY EROR

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:70)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:150)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:423)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:484)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:209)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:125)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.send(EmailMessage.java:240)
    at schedule.SendEmail.sendEmail(SendEmail.java:50)
    at schedule.servlet.doPost(servlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:709)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:639)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:58)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest.executeRequest(HttpClientWebRequest.java:279)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:700)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EwsX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(EwsX509TrustManager.java:81)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: You may find the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: It doesn't say nothing about Certificate.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my prob. I found on net, next tutorials:

It's  well explained,

http://www.dekho.com.au/help/32/default.htm?turl=Documents%2Faddingacertificateintothejavacertificatestore.htm

This, is video tut. found on youtube, explain how to install a certificate and how to add it to keystore, even is for ColdFusion  I think it is useful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewT4aud-xww

Answer (score 1):

Need to add your domain's certificate (which is probably not signed by a public CA?) to the trust store for your application instance.  See:

[Error while sending mails using EWSJavaAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301171/error-while-sending-mails-using-ewsjavaapi)